# User login session issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a basic login system for a website where users can login and retrieve their data. The issue is that once I log in the session picks random data and display them. While I want each user to access only their own data from the database using their credentials. Can anyone help me solve this please?

This is what I'm getting when I echo the query. Eamil is NULL while users login using their email and password.

SELECT DISTINCT s.id AS 'searchid', s.description as 'searchname', so.id AS 'sourceid', so.description as 'service' FROM `contact` `c` JOIN `deliveryreg` `d` ON `c`.`contact_id` = `d`.`idcontact` JOIN `searchsource` `ss` ON `ss`.`id` = `d`.`idsearchsource` JOIN `search` `s` ON `s`.`id` = `ss`.`idsearch` JOIN `source` `so` ON `so`.`id` = `ss`.`idsource` WHERE `c`.`statusid` = 1 AND `email` IS NULL AND `so`.`id` IN('1', '5', '8') ORDER BY `s`.`description`

```
/**
 * @name: Login model
 * 
 */
class Login_model extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function validate_user($data) {
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('c.contact_id, name, email, password, level, c.statusid');
        $this->db->from('contact c');
        $this->db->join('deliveryreg d', 'c.contact_id = d.idcontact');
        $this->db->join('ClientLogin cl', 'cl.idcontact = c.contact_id');
        $this->db->where('c.statusid = 1');
        $this->db->where('email', $data['email']);
        $this->db->where('password', $data['password']);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function getSearch(){
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select(" s.id AS 'searchid',s.description as 'searchname',so.id AS 'sourceid',so.description as 'service'");
        $this->db->from('contact c');
        $this->db->join('deliveryreg d', 'c.contact_id = d.idcontact');
        $this->db->join('searchsource ss', 'ss.id = d.idsearchsource');
        $this->db->join('search s', 's.id = ss.idsearch');
        $this->db->join('source so', 'so.id = ss.idsource');
        $this->db->where('c.statusid = 1'); 
        $this->db->where('email');
        $ids = array('1','5','8');
        $this->db->where_in('so.id', $ids);
        $this->db->order_by('s.description', 'so.description');

        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        return $query->result();

    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }
}
```

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $this->load->database();

        if(empty($this->session->userdata('c.contact_id'))) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', '<div class="alert alert-warning text-center">Ooops. You don\'t have access!</div>');
            redirect('login');
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        $contact_id = $this->session->userdata('c.contact_id');
        $data['contact_id'] = $contact_id;
        $data['query'] = $this->login_model->getSearch($contact_id);
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }

    public function logout() {
        $data = ['c.contact_id', 'email'];
        $this->session->unset_userdata($data);
        redirect('login');
    }


}
```

Comment: What is output or error ??

Comment: I see you calling getSearch with a parameter, however the function doesn't have a parameter set to receive in the first place

Comment: @Abdulla There is no error. It's not just pulling the correct data

Comment: `print_r($data['query'])` and check

Comment: @Abdulla it's actually not picking the email for some reasons. When I echo the query, the email says NULL